# ANCOVA analysis

Tags: anova, ancova

I'd like to perform an ANCOVA analysis for my study.
The following features:

- 3 groups and 1 DV (continuous)
- ANOVA and post hoc analyses showed  a statistically significant differences
- There are some covariates (dichotomous and continuous; i.e. risk factors)

The aim is to "eliminate" or "control" the effect of the covariates on the DV.
After checking the assumptions to perform the ANCOVA, which covariates should I include?
For example, some dichotomous covariates showed a different distribution between the 3 groups (Chi-square and Kruskal-Wallis tests) while others did not.
Should they all be included, or just the significant ones?

Answer (score 0):

You should include the covariates that you deem to be [confounders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) in the relationship between your “treatment” (your three groups) and dependent variable.

Look into DAGs (Directed Acyclic Graphs) to understand better what to include or not.